# Возможно ли создать веб-сервис, возвращающий дженерики? Spring 3.

Tags: spring, java

День добрый!

Возможно ли через Spring 3 создать веб-сервис, который будет возвращать коллекцию дженериков?

К примеру, веб-сервис который под запросу с классом возвращает все объекты данного класса из базы.

?

Comment: раз у вас возникла такая проблема возможно вы пытаетесь впихнуть generic не там где надо. с трудом представляю веб сервис который сможет работать с запросами а-ля:
1) верни мне всех лошадей у которых 4 копыта
2) верни мне цвет помидор для сортов (А, Б, В) 
...

Comment: Этому почему же? Просто вопрос: верни мне список лошадей.. а вместо этого выходит, что нам вернут список неизвестных объектов, которые ещё проверить надо, а лошади ли там.

Comment: Какой тип веб-сервисов вы используете? SOAP вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Использую jax-ws через spring 3. Запросы которые нужны очень простые и понятные: верните все объекты класса A. Я не хочу писать 10 одинаковых методов для этой задачи на каждый класс.

Answer (score 1):

Сложный вопрос... Из-за [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) информация о дженерике потеряется при компиляции, если только корневой бин не является дженериком. Проще говоря, если корневой бин обычный класс то есть шанс что через рефлексию тип переданных данных сможет быть распознан. В общем надо пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически такое возможно, так как в WSDL можно указать тип коллекции. Однако, на практике такая возможность зависит от того, какую реализацию SOAP (или что вы там используете) вы используете.

PS: type erasure в данном случае не помеха.